# What is a single conductor temperature sensor called?

Tags: temperature, probe

What is a conductive temperature probe called? They're relatively massy metal rods (5-8mm thick, 5-15cm long) that have a single *conductor (NOT 2 conductor wire)* to connect to the thermostat.

The connecting conductor wire is reasonably thick to (presumably) conduct the heat effectively to the measuring device.

I replaced one in my oven, and my spa has one too.

(I ask, because I broke the wire on my spa one, and searching the internet without a technical continually brings up thermo couples and other sensors)

*Updated to help others:* I'm looking at something like this is the sort of thing:
[image: Thermostat]

Comment: It's called a thermocouple. Search on any of the appliance repair sites and you'll probably find a replacement.

Comment: From http://www.thermocoupleinfo.com/: "Thermocouples consist of two wire legs made from different metals. The wires legs are welded together at one end, creating a junction... When the junction experiences a change in temperature, a voltage is created.". One conductor/wire, therefore no voltage. If it _is_ a thermo couple (makes sense from the name, after all), then it must be a specific type that I can't find the name of.

Comment: The [housing](http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200332731_200332731) is the other conductor.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. So is there a name for this type of thermocouple? So the housing (my "conductor" turns out to be very mildly hollow if it's not crushed) is a conductor, then what's the other conductor? It does have an acidic smelling liquid inside (could it be a chemical reaction from getting wet?).

Comment: And... not fixable - it seems I need to replace. I've found [the replacement thermostat](http://www.newzealandspaparts.co.nz/products/thermostat-rc-18-resetable-ampac-1) but I don't particularly want to shell out $100... so I just need to figure out what type it is and then search for replacement couples?

Comment: Dunno. <padding>

Comment: NZ? ............................

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This task is often performed by a theromocouple, such as EMFields describe.
However ...

Your device is a "Capillary Thermostat". The sensor is filled with a substance which increases in pressure with heating and a bellows in the control end actuates a switch at a preset temperature. Once broken they are essentially not repairable.

You may be able to find a direct equivalent elsewhere and other versions which cover the same temperature range and which have the same electrical contacts could be used as a replacement.
As ever, YMMV.*

Another seller [here](http://www.electrical.co.nz/ego-thermostat-55%C2%BAc-manual-reset-rc18) - $ unknown.

Often [a very good source](http://firesales.co.nz/Capillary%20Thermostats?p=gcb&gclid=CjwKEAiAo8emBRCX_OqU4qek6y8SJACzgf8fAvgeGS7OYpFuXA-XKkuZM4JBK9Kq_aP0RWpYQyCIYRoCkNrw_wcB) if they have something suitable.

---

[Wikipedia - also known as a 'freeze stat'])(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze_stat)

[Real world examples](http://www.rathgeber-gmbh.de/pages/capillary_e.html)

[and more](http://www.tempco.com/Catalog/Section%2013-pdf/Bulb_Capillary_Thermostats.pdf)

[Lots of pictures](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=capillary+thermostat&biw=1097&bih=614&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=tffRVPiOKIv98AWDnYLoDg&ved=0CCUQsAQ) - all linked tro related web pages.

---

*YMMV - Your Mileage WILL Vary.

Comment: I *did* think that crimp in the bottom was significant somehow... also turns out I had no clue and linked to a High Limit breaker rather than an adjustable... but you still came through!